# Using more than one thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, task-queue, worker

I'm new to concurrent programing and have been working on code which has a queue of items to be processed, this is passed to some worker threads, the number specified by the user. At the moment I've just tried to do it with two worker threads plus the main.

```
private static class workerThread extends Thread {

        workerThread(){
            super();
        }


        public void run(){
             while (!workQueue.isEmpty()) {

            String x = workQueue.remove();
            //System.out.println("work queue size: " + workQueue.size());
            Vector<String> list2 = new Vector<String>((Vector) table.get(x));
            list2 = process(x, list2);
            //System.out.println(list2 + "list2");
            table.put(x, list2);

            //System.out.println(x + "key" + "value" + vvv);

        }

        }
```

That's the thread workerthread class, I've tried to call it just by creating two new threads:

```
workerThread wt = new workerThread();
    workerThread wt2 = new workerThread();
    wt.start();
    wt2.start();
    try {
        wt.join();
        wt2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(includeCrawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is right, or will have any benfit due to waiting for the joins? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much cleaner and scalable way to do this is to use a thread pool created by the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class.

By the way, the `Vector` class is obsolete and should not be used anymore - use `ArrayList` instead and dump whatever book or tutorial where you learned to use `Vector` - it's more than a decade out of date.

Comment: I think Sarconi would benefit from understanding threads first

Comment: I had a little look at a thread pool but it seemed a bit complicated for this exercise. Oh, I used a a Vector because it's synchronised. I didn't realise it was out of date.

Comment: Coming from C++ development I can definitely say it's hard not to use `Vector`, just for mental consistency. Not saying it's better, just that might be why the poster used it.

Comment: @Sarconi: It's definitely not more complicated than manually managing a variable number threads. And the synchronization of Vector seems irrelevant when each instance is only used by one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few references, I think you want to use a `BlockingQueue` along with an `ExecutorService` and a `Runnable` or `Callable`.

`final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());` perhaps even an instance variable (private static final ExecutorService POOL = ...). For an I/O bound application you might want to use more threads than the available processors. Then again you don't want to use `Vector`. Use another `List` implementation (usually `ArrayList` is the one to use).

BTW: If you want to master concurrent programming you might also want to read about Akka and Actors/STM instead of using the usual shared mutability model.

Edit: I would definately recommend http://pragprog.com/book/vspcon/programming-concurrency-on-the-jvm and Effective Java from Josh(ua) Bloch.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have to use Executors. This is an example just for reference. It works on a single thread, but I think it's a good start for you. It's easily adaptable to an arbitrary number of threads.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<MyObject> f =
    executor.submit(new Callable<MyObject>() {

      @Override
      public MyObject call() throws Exception {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        // do stuff
        return obj;
      }

    });

MyObject myObject =
    new MyObject();

try {
  myObject = f.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // stuff
}
catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // stuff
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
  // stuff
}
finally {
  executor.shutdown();
}
```

In this case I wanted to wait at most 500ms before timeout, but this is optional.
Hope this could help.

Comment: java Future.get == blocking == kills scalability

Comment: @ViktorKlang : do you have some more information? I'd like to go deeper in that topic. Could you share some links? 10x

Comment: blocking == pauses Threads == less Threads active == less work can be done == less scalability == less performance

Comment: In your example you have 2 Threads, the caller and the Thread in the ExecutorService. When you do Future.get, it means that you have 1 Thread paused and 1 Thread doing work. If you have 100 callers you have 100 Thread paused and 1 Thread doing work.